# Echo an index from a sessioned array

Tags: php, arrays, session, indexing, echo

I have a session that stores an array.

Let's say, my sessions are cars and music that each stores the following:

```
<?php
$_Session['cars'] =array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
$_Session['music'] = array("Beatles", "Carpenters", "Sting");
?>
```

Now, how can I echo the following based on my sessions:

```
BMW Sting
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: `echo $_SESSION['cars'][1].' '.$_SESSION['music'][2];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try with array index value. i.e session array index value

```
<?php
session_start(); // To enable session to current page
$_SESSION['cars'] =array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
$_SESSION['music'] = array("Beatles", "Carpenters", "Sting");
echo $_SESSION['cars'][1]; // will print "BMW"
echo $_SESSION['music'][2]; // will print "Sting"
?>
```

Comment: Actually, no. $_Session != $_SESSION, so your example won't work.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for this. I thought it wouldn't work with the double []'s. I tried doing this but I had an error in my session. Just forgot about the session start. Thanks again! Have a nice day!

Comment: welcome @coding.bird, $_SESSION is global array. If using double [] is multidimensional array that will work. If you got solution from answer, accept answer others also use of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add `session_start()` at the top of your code, then

```
echo $_SESSION['cars'][1];
echo $_SESSION['music'][2];
```

Note the case of `$_SESSION` - your snippet uses the wrong case and won't store data in the `$_SESSION` array